# OpenCV -- how to interpret contents of cv::imread object

Tags: c++

I am new to OpenCV and have tried to copy the contents of a cv::imread object to an array. When I print the contents, however, I get a bunch of characters like this

```
^N
^X
^Y
^Q
^[
^U
```

How am I to interpret this as RGB values? I was expecting values in the range of 0 to 255 and I don't understand what these characters mean. I would like to put the values into an array of pixels but, with no numbers, that's impossible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If this is RGB think about bytes, not chars!